# Require gem automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I created a gem which defines a `Rails::Railtie`.
Everything works as expected, except that I have to include the main file of the gem (`lib/gem.rb`) in my `application.rb` so it is executed.

Is there any way to do this automatically?
I checked some gems, but I could not figure out how.

Comment: Is the lib directory in your load path?

Comment: When you say: `gem 'gem_name'` Rubygems inject it in your require chain. Now, your gem file which is to be loaded should be `gem_name/lib/gem_name.rb` Are you sure that you have followed this structure?

Comment: That was the problem, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

The name of my gem was slightly different from the files' name (`gem-name` vs `lib/gem_name.rb`), so I have to put this to my `Gemfile`:

`gem 'gem-name', require: 'gem_name'`

Comment: I believe that you don't need to have: `require: 'gem_name'` here if you change your gem-name to gem_name.

Comment: I am not sure but this might help: http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#consistent-naming and http://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/ to understand the file naming conventions in Ruby.

Comment: Ah I see. That should mean I can also put my gem file to ``lib/gem/name.rb`` and it should work. Ima try it out